# Docker Container Microsoft/iis Username and Password

Tags: iis, docker, iis-7, docker-compose, docker-machine

freshly pulled and started the officially IIS docker container from Microsoft.
Works fine and i can browse the starting IIS page, but while trying to connect with IIS Server Manager i get asked about USERNAME and PASSWORD which is not provided.

How can i connect to the container using IIS Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok turns out it has integrated auth. so if you want to connect, install the management service for iis and create a local admin user, works like a charm